# jquery trigger bug

Tags: jquery, triggers

I have this

```
...
<li style="padding: 50px;">
   <a href="blabla" style="background:red;">Click Me</a>
</li>
...
```

As you all may know that the `<a>` tag will be smaller in size.
I want to use jquery as so...

```
$('li').click(function (){
   $(this).find('a').trigger('click');//does not work :(
   alert($(this).find('a').attr('href'););//returns blabla//which is correct
});
```

Any ideas why the `<a>` cannot be triggered in this way ? 
PS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery's `trigger` function will call event handlers registered using jQuery.

It will not simulate a real click.

Instead, you can write

```
location = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
```

Comment: Yep that did the trick :)... i think jq should consider triggering the native click :) on <a> tags...

Comment: @Val: That's only possible in IE.

Comment: they could use window.location.href

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(this).find('a').trigger('click')
```

Only triggers the javascript event , and not the default events

Here is the fix

```
$('li').click(function (){
    var url =  $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    location.href= url
});
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/EbQZM/4/)

You could simplify it too:

```
$('li').click(function (){
    location.href= $(this).find('a').attr('href');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$(this).find("a:first").click();
```

I guess it's because you haven't bound the "a"'s onclick event to anything using jQuery :-)

Comment: Firing a `.click()` will cause the `<a>` to look for what to do when it receives `onclick`. If he doesn't have that defined, nothing happens. It's the same as `onmouseover` etc.

Comment: Then I wonder why my test on my own site: $("#topmenu ul li ul li").find("a:first").click(); works just perfect?

Answer (score 0):

I think CSS is enough to do what you want...

What you want is just link tags take all `<li>` space.
In many cases `display:block;` on `<a>` tags is enough but I don't know anything about your HTML/CSS ^^

Comment: Maybe you would like to elaborate on that :)

Comment: Thanks! But unfortunately I think my answer won't be visible =(

Answer (score 0):

With JavaScript you can't have the browser's native click simulated. You would have to setup an event handler for your link that indeed does get fired once you trigger 'click'. From there you could go with SLaks `location = ...` method.